# How do I find my friends on CouchSurfing?

Tags: couchsurfing

I have a couple of friends/acquaintances I know use CouchSurfing but the interface is extremely un-user friendly with regard to finding particular people rather than finding a couch in a given place.

How can I use couchsuring.org to find a friend by either name or email address?

Comment: The interface is also extremely user-unfriendly regarding finding couches!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't find a way to search by email address and both of the people I was looking for were listed under pseudonyms which is common for obvious reasons but I did find some things.

[There is an advanced search feature](http://www.couchsurfing.org/mapsurf.html?form=advanced)

I think it was formerly not quite as difficult to find as it now is with very recent changes where most searching seems to be done from a new front page.

The advanced search has many fields:

- Has Couch?
- Allowing at least
- ♿ (Wheelchair accessible)
- Verification Level
- Vouched
- Ambassadors only
- Name
- Keywords
- Language
- Gender
- In My Groups
- In My Friends
- Has picture
- Minimum Age
- Maximum Age
- Last Login
- Results per page
- Order by
- Search location by text
- Search location by selection
- In the region

You might have to get creative, in my case I found both people by a combination of location, not so common languages they speak, and putting cities or countries I know they've visited in the keyword field.

Comment: Nice, a name based advanced search actually seems to work. Earlier I've resorted to looking at a *group* (such as "Helsinki") to which the person probably/possibly belongs, and browsing the (alphabetical) member list. But that's far from user-friendly too, especially with large groups.

Comment: That “mapsurf” search is broken. – For examples, if you limit the couches to “yes”, you get the results, but clicking on a profile brings you to someones else’s.

Comment: Limiting the couches to “coffee” in Beijing, I got 32 results. Clicking on one, brought to me to a profile which was not even listed on the results (which I set to 100 per page), but also matched the search (Beijing, coffee only).

Answer (score 2):

I've found my friend by clicking in MY profile "Direct profile URL" and replacing the last part of the url with my friend's username:

http://www.couchsurfing.org/people/xxxxxxxxxx/

Comment: I guess it's easier when you already know your friend's username (-:

Answer (score -1):

try this : http://www.couchsurfing.org/mapsurf.html

This appears to be the older search page layout, which I didn't know was still there. I can't find anything easily with the new layout. It was never easy searching CS, I can't believe they've made it less user friendly. Didn't think it was possible :(

try putting your friends name or something about them in the keyword section. Good luck :)

Comment: Seems gone now :(